# The metabase key 'LM/W3SVC' could not be found, but IIS 10 is installed

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

I try to publish my website from Visual Studio.
The connection to remote is working, I checked, I clicked verify connection before.

When I click on Publish I get this error:

```
The metabase key '/LM/W3SVC' could not be found.
Unable to access the IIS configuration system. Please make sure you have IIS 7 (or later) installed.
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2B-133B-4602-8452-8344546344} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).   deploy      0
```

I'm on Windows Server 2019 on EC2 and IIS 10 is installed. Maybe it needs more configuration?

Comment: Did you look up the error code given? What did you learn? What have you tried?

Comment: @music2myear all I've seen is that it has to do something with apps for 32 bit machines. However Visual Studio does not give me option to choose anything other than "Any CPU". I don't have x86 in that list.

Comment: Btw, I already set my application pool to enable 32-bit applications on IIS

Comment: @music2myear update: I found how to build specifically for 32-bit applications! (In Visual Studio > Project > <project name> properties > Build > Platform Target! Now it works! Thank you for the hint which made me look once again!!! Do you know why it doesn't work if I target Any CPU? I assumed that Any CPU means for 32-bit too!